# Ordering is not maintained in latex after build

Tags: latex

```
\subsubsection{Greedy}
```

the code snippet:

```
A greedy coloring is a coloring of the vertices of a graph formed by a greedy algorithm that considers the vertices of the graph in sequence and assigns each vertex its first available color. Greedy colorings do not in general use the minimum number of colors possible. However, they have been used in mathematics as a technique for proving other results about colorings and in computer science as a heuristic to find colorings with few colors. In this heuristic algorithm, once a vertex is colored, its color never changes.

\textbf{Input:} A simple undirected graph G with vertices $V(G)$ = {$v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, . . . , $v_{n}$}. (The list of colors to be drawn from will be {1, 2, . . ., n}; GCA does not necessarily use all of these colors.\\
\textbf{Output:} A vertex-coloring of G.
\paragraph{Basic Algorithm:\\}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Greedy Coloring Algorithm}
\label{GCA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\FOR{$i = 1$ to $n$} 
\STATE $L_{i}$ =$\lbrace$1,...,i$\rbrace$($L_{i}$ is the list of colors that may be assigned to $v_{i}$)
\ENDFOR
\FOR{$i = 1$ to $n$} 
\STATE $C_{i}$ $\leftarrow$ the first color in $L_{i}$( $C_{i}$ is the color assigned to $v_{i}$)
\ENDFOR \\
\WHILE{$i$ $<$ $j$ and ($v_{i}$,$v_{j}$)$\neq$ E(G)} 

\STATE $L_{j}$ $:=$ $L_{j}$ $\backslash$ $C_{i}$
\ENDWHILE
\STATE Return each vertex, the color it was assigned, and the total number of colors used.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\paragraph{Findings}
Time Complexity: O($V^{2}$ + E) in worst case.
```

the pdf format:
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG0Nd.png)

[image: prob in latex]
[image]

what i am facing problem is that ordering is not maintained in the paper.i       want to see the paper in the order in which i have written in latex. But it is not happening.
    [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CpaZ.png)
    [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vm5QN.png)
    [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG0Nd.png)

Comment: Sorry, I won't try to read a screenshot of text; why didn't you just copy and paste the LaTeX source code?! Also, from rough eyeballing, I don't even see any reordering. And what's up with the images at the end? They stand unexplained.

Comment: problem is that in which order i wrote code in pdf format they are not showing the order like: first algo then another sec but here algo is shown later. i wan to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is that you've written the algorithm inside an `algorithm` environment, which floats like a `figure` or `table`.  If you want a sequential presentation (output) that matches your input, then you may want to try something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible,amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\bigO}[1]{\mathcal{O}(#1)}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\textbf{Input:}]}%
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\textbf{Output:}]}%
\newcommand{\AlgBlankLine}{\par\nobreak\vspace*{.5\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{Basic Algorithm}\leavevmode

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Greedy Coloring Algorithm (GCA)}\label{GCA}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \INPUT A simple undirected graph~$G$ with vertices $V(G) = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$. (The list of colors to be drawn from will be $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$; 
      GCA does not necessarily use all of these colors.)
    \OUTPUT A vertex-coloring of~$G$.
    \AlgBlankLine
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $n$}
      \STATE $L_i = \{1,\dots,i\}$ ($L_i$ is the list of colors that may be assigned to~$v_i$)
    \ENDFOR
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $n$}
      \STATE $C_i \leftarrow \text{the first color in $L_i$}$ ($C_i$ is the color assigned to~$v_i$)
    \ENDFOR
    \WHILE{$i < j$ and $(v_i,v_j) \neq E(G)$}
      \STATE $L_j := L_j \setminus C_i$
    \ENDWHILE
    \STATE Return each vertex, the color it was assigned, and the total number of colors used.
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\paragraph{Findings}%
Time Complexity: $\bigO{V^2 + E}$ in worst case.

\end{document}
```

Note the following:

1. I've used the [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package's formatting and layout instead of pure [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms). The latter, from the `algorithms` bundle, loads the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) which provides the `[H]` float specifier. This changes the behaviour of the float to STAY `H`ERE and not float any more.
2. Include your **input** and **output** as part of the algorithm. It makes more sense.
3. `\leavevmode` (or `\mbox{}`) is important after `\paragraph{Basic Algorithm}` as it actually starts the paragraph.
4. Some other formatting updates.

My preference would be that you reference the algorithm within the text, and let it float where it may need to go within the document. Using the above-mentioned `[H]` float specifier will put the `algorithm` block in-place and correspond to your LaTeX input, but it will also cause problems if the block occurs around a page boundary. Letting it float avoids that.

Comment: one problem again arises :( unnecessary gaps between section & algo. what to do?? plz help!!

Comment: @pufi: Insert a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` or choose whichever (negative) length you want to move the content.

Comment: can algorithm be displayed within 2 pg? suppose,section: basic algo in pg-1 and its algo is in pg 2. but i want it in pg 1? i think len of the algo is out of bound of pg 1 so it is bound to be in pg 2??

Comment: @pufi: That's what I mention at the end of my post. You'll have problems around the page boundary. If you want it to break naturally, then you have to post the content outside of the `algorithm` environment and *mimic* the idea of a structure that has a `\caption`. It's not as clean, but it's doable.